# Rename columns with regex and Pandas to extract contents between specific punctuations

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

Given a test dataset as follows:

```
  city district  ... Q3:*your age[open question]  Q4:*skill[open question]
0   bj       cy  ...                          45                              R
1   bj       cy  ...                          34                         Python
```

I need to rename columns by using regex to extract the contents between `*` and `[`, also removing `your` if they exist. Please note in real case, I have many Questions columns as below.

```
df.columns
Out[112]: 
Index(['city', 'district', 'name', 'Q1:*your tel[open question]',
       'Q2:*your profession[close question]', 'Q3:*your age[open question]',
       'Q4:*skill[open question]'],
      dtype='object')
```

The expected columns will like this:

```
['city', 'district', 'name', 'tel', 'profession', 'age', 'skill']
```

How could I do that in Pandas and regex? Many thanks at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever facing problems like this, you may wanna give yourself some time to think what pattern does match what you want. For this I'd recommend [this site](https://regexr.com), where you can paste your target text and try some patterns out. It takes some time, but that is how we actually learn (regex are always a good exercise for the brain).

For your case, the pattern you desire is `r'\*(your)?(.*)\['`, where the second matching group is the word to be new name of the column. So you can try something like :

```
import re

pattern = r'\*(your)?(.*)\['

print('# Before\n', df.columns)
df = df.rename({
     col: re.search(pattern, col).group(2).strip() 
     if re.search(pattern, col) 
     else col 
     for col in df.columns
     }, axis=1)
print('# After\n', df.columns)
```

And the output will be:

```
# Before
 Index(['city', 'district', 'name', 'Q1:*your tel[open question]',
       'Q2:*your profession[close question]', 'Q3:*your age[open question]',
       'Q4:*skill[open question]'],
      dtype='object')
# After
 Index(['city', 'district', 'name', 'tel', 'profession', 'age', 'skill'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks, https://regex101.com/ is also quite helpful.

Comment: I suppose you have used two patterns, could pls you post them on the code part so I can test?

Comment: Sorry, there's only one pattern but I forgot to add it to the answer. I'll edit it right away

Comment: I don't understand, with this pattern, how does it work out for `Q4:*skill[open question]`, which has no `your` inside?

Comment: It has a `?` after `(your)`, which means it'll match 0 or 1 occurrences of  `your`. Give it a try and you'll see it working

Answer (score 1):

```
df13 = df.filter(regex = '^[^Q]', axis = 1) #Isolate columns without Q
df12 = df.filter(regex = '^Q', axis = 1) #isolate columns with Q
x = df.filter(regex = '^Q', axis = 1).reindex(df.filter(regex = '^Q', axis = 1).\
columns.str.findall('([a-z]+(?=\[))').str.join(','),\
axis = "columns").columns # transform column names with q
df12.columns=list(x) # reset df12 column names
pd.concat([df13, df12], axis = 1)
```

Example Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'city':[1], 'district':[1], 'name':[1], 'Q1:*your tel[open question]':[1],
       'Q2:*your profession[close question]':[1], 'Q3:*your age[open question]':[1],
       'Q4:*skill[open question]':[1]})
```

print(df)

```
 city  district  name  Q1:*your tel[open question]  \
0     1         1     1                            1   

   Q2:*your profession[close question]  Q3:*your age[open question]  \
0                                    1                            1   

   Q4:*skill[open question]  
0                         1
```

Outcome

```
    city  district  name  tel  profession  age  skill
0     1         1     1    1           1    1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cols = []
for i in df.columns:
    if re.search(r'Q\d:',i) != None:
        cols.append(re.match(r'^Q\d:\*(your\s)?([\w]*)',i).group(2))
    else:
        cols.append(i)
```

Oneliner substitute for above:

```
[(re.match(r'^Q\d:\*(your\s)?([\w]*)',i).group(2)) if re.search(r'Q\d:',i) is not None else i for i in df.columns]
```

Both prints:

```
['city', 'district', 'name', 'tel', 'profession', 'age', 'skill']
```

Comment: Thanks, what does `group(2)` represent in your code?

Comment: Oh there are two capture groups in that regex pattern, one for optional  `(your\s)?` and one for the actual string that you want as the column name `([\w]*)`. So I am using `group(2)` to capture the second capture group value.

Comment: just noticed that it is similar thing that the @ralubrusto has also used in his answer `col: re.search(pattern, col).group(2).strip()`

Comment: Yes, I try my real data with `if re.search(r'Q\d:',i) != None: print(cols)`, but it returns mutliple empty lists. I didn't figure out why this happens. No this errors for @ralubrusto's solution.